# problem in inserting entries into my database

Tags: rest, api, codeigniter

I have created a view page for login and upload but when i press the submit button it does not get uploaded into my database..

I have used insert() command.

this is my controller,i have called model beforehand  using 
             $this->load->model('upanel_model');  now i want to code such that whenever a user presses submit button the data gets inserted in the database.

```
       public function upload_post(){
            $config['upload_path']    =   './uploads/'; 
            $config['allowed_types']  =   'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']       =   '1000';
            $config['max_width']      =   '1024';
            $config['max_height']     =   '768';
            $config['file_name']      =   '$pdfname';  
            $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());                
        }     
     else{
            $data1 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $data = $this->upload->data('full_path');
            $pdfType = $data1['upload_data']['file_ext'];
            $pdf_link = $pdfName.$pdfType;
            $table = 'register';
            $data['email']=$this->post('email');
            $data['password']= $this->post('password');
            $data['file_path']=$pdf_link;
            $data2 = $this->upload->data('full_path');
            $userdata=$this->$model_name->insert($table,$data);
     if($userdata){
            $data_response['status']=1;
            $data_response['msg']="Successfully inserted details";

            $this->response($data_response);
                } else{                        
                     $data_response['status']=0;
                     $data_response['msg']="Unable To insert details";
                     $this->response($data_response);
           }    
    }
   public function upload_get(){
    $this->load->view('view');       
    }
```

this is my model named upanel_model.php which inserts the data

```
       <?php
        function insert($table,$data){
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
       }
       ?>
```

this is my view named view.php that call my upload api

```
      <body>   
      <?php echo form_open_multipart('uPanel/do_upload'); ?>
      <div class = "header">
          <h1>Login Now</h1>
      </div>
      <form method= "post" action= "upload">
      <div class="input-group">
          <label>email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" >
      </div>
      <div class ="input-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="text" name="password">  
      </div>
      <div class = "input-group">
      <input type="submit" class ="btn" name="login_now" value="submit" >                                
        </div> 
      <p>   NOT MEMBER? SIGN UP 
      </p>    
      <input type="file" name="userfile" size="90" />
      <br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="upload" />
      </body>
```

Comment: where you used your controller `insert` function? and where is your model code for insert code?

Comment: i edited the answer  my model is the second code where i defined insert function

Comment: did you debug in your model->insert(); that $data is not empty?